# How can I recover my offline lost achievements and saved games?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

Some years ago I logged in XBox Live for first time in my XBox, for some reasons I stopped using it in Live and only played offline. One day I recovered my gamertag in a friend's console, but that was the last update of my gamertag in Live, with only like 3000G.
From that date I earned a lot of achievements offline, around 8000G more, but today I decided to log in XBox Live again in my console and when I recovered my gamertag, it replaced everything - my profile is exactly the same I had around 2 or 3 years ago when I logged in my friend's console.

I'm again at 3380G and it appears that there is no record in my console about all my offline achievements and saved games (for example, Gears of War or Call of Duty campaigns are again at 0, as if i had never played them in my console, BUT I can just select "resume game" and I can continue as I left it before the whole recovering process).

Is there any way I can get those saved games and achievements to my online profile?

Comment: This is definitely how it used to work but I was pretty sure they fixed it. Best proof I can provide is here unfortunately tho: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/how-do-xbox-live-achievements-work-if-youre-offline

Answer (score 3):

You can find a discussion about this [here](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/f/12/t/15384.aspx), but the simple answer is no. Those achievements were earned offline, so Xbox Live has no record of you ever doing them. When you recovered your gamertag, it reset it to the last time it was seen by Live, when you only had 3000G, effectively erasing all gamerscore accumulated between the last time you were online and the recovery. If you would have gone back online before recovering, say from your console at home, it would have updated and seen those achievements, adding them to your gamerscore. But the recovery wiped all your offline work away.

The reason you still have saved data for games is because saved data and achievements are separate things; your hard drive has the saved data, but Live tracks the achievements online. Any data that was saved offline should still be saved on your hard drive, so the actually progress in game progression should not have been lost. I'm sorry to say you have lost the gamerscore you had before recovering your gamertag.

Comment: You also MIGHT have to start with fresh game data to regain those achievements.  If the game thinks that it has already given you an achievement for accomplishing something, it will likely not give it to you again (even though you don't technically have the achievement).