# Can I update offline earned Xbox360 achievements to Live without recovering my gamertag?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I recover my offline lost achievements and saved games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82361/how-can-i-recover-my-offline-lost-achievements-and-saved-games)

About 4 years ago I connected to Xbox Live for the first time.  I attained around 4000G before my family moved out to the sticks-as it were- where we don't have any good high-speed internet services.  I played offline for a year or so (within which I recovered my gamertag several times to different friends' Xboxes) and gained a few thousand more offline. This is where things went wrong…. I heard the Xbox dashboard had an update, so I brought by Xbox to a friend’s house to download it. I recovered my gamertag to **my own** xbox in the process... this-of course-wiped all the achievements I had gotten offline. I went from 9,000G's back to 4000G's. This made me sad. And mad. But that's over, I’ve researched that, that isn’t my question.

Since then I have continued playing offline, and have about 10,000G's again. I know that if I were to go somewhere with high-speed internet and recover my gamertag to my own xbox, I would lose everything all over again, like last time. My question is **Is there a way to connect to Xbox Live without recovering my gamertag, but updating all my new achievements to my account?**  Maybe it will from just connecting to the internet?
I feel like there has to be away. Or am I just trapped into never being able to use Xbox Live again without losing a ton of achievements?  I just don't want to lose it all again.
Thanks for any help I can get!

This is the closest answer/question to my problem that I've found: [How can I recover my offline lost achievements and saved games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82361/how-can-i-recover-my-offline-lost-achievements-and-saved-games)

Comment: Sorry, Jacob, but that question you linked is literally exactly the same problem as you're having.  Since it's the same question, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.  A quick read of the answer says that if you go online with your Xbox, though, it should update your gamertag, if you've been playing under it the whole time.

Comment: @fbueckert 
Okay, thanks. I realize that now, I guess I feel like I tried that the first time, and it didn't work. It's been so long though that I'm not sure. I'll just have to try it I guess.